Redissolving calcium carbonate after heating
I need to redissolve calcium carbonate in a water sample after evaporating some of the sample, which I expect will cause the calcium to precipitate. I'm thinking a relatively weak acid is best to lower the pH because any organic matter needs to be preserved, but I'm not sure exactly which acid and concentration would be most effective to dissolve only the calcium. Does anyone have any experience in this situation or advice?
It's a water sample that will be filtered to determine the mass of particulates present, but I'm worried about the precipitate adding additional mass. The samples are composed of rainfall that flowed down tree stems or fell through the leaves of the canopy, so what needs to be preserved is organic matter found on the bark and leaves of trees. These must not be dissolved.

Dissolve "only the calcium?" What else is present, and must not be dissolved again?

It's a water sample that will be filtered to determine the mass of particulates present, but I'm worried about the precipitate adding additional mass. The samples are composed of rainfall that flowed down tree stems or fell through the leaves of the canopy, so what needs to be preserved is organic matter found on the bark and leaves of trees. These must not be dissolved.

That is essential information that belongs in the question, which you should edit. The more effort put into the question, the more likely it would get a useful answer.
